# How do you concisely create a Date in Purescript, when you know statically that the year + month + date are valid

Tags: date, purescript

`Data.Date.canonicalDate` constructs a `Date` value, but you need a `Year`, `Month` and `Day` value as arguments:

- Since `Month` is known statically, you can just hard-code it: e.g. `June`
- `Year` and `Day` can't be hard-coded, though, even though you know them statically. You have to call `toEnum`, and that only gives you a `Maybe Year` / `Maybe Day`.

My current solution is this, which seems like a crazy hack:

```
hackyMakeDate :: Int -> Month -> Int -> Date
hackyMakeDate year month day = fromMaybe (canonicalDate bottom bottom bottom) maybeDate
  where
    maybeDate = do
      year' <- toEnum year
      day' <- toEnum day
      pure $ canonicalDate year' month day'
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're ok with just crashing when year and/or day are out of range (a decision I strongly urge you to rethink), then you can use [`fromJust`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-maybe/4.0.0/docs/Data.Maybe#v:fromJust) (which is a partial function) along with [`unsafePartial`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-partial/2.0.0/docs/Partial.Unsafe#v:unsafePartial) to hide the partiality:

```
makeDate :: Int -> Month -> Int -> Date
makeDate year month day = 
    unsafePartial $ fromJust $ 
       canonicalDate <$> toEnum year <@> month <*> toEnum day
```

Alternatively, you can opt to not hide the partiality:

```
partialMakeDate :: Partial => Int -> Month -> Int -> Date
partialMakeDate year month day = 
    fromJust $ 
       canonicalDate <$> toEnum year <@> month <*> toEnum day
```

This way, at least your consumers will know that the function is really partial.